# Do browsers remember events?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I would like to know what the browser does about events that happen while scripts are currently running.  Does the browser just ignore these events or does it store them and execute them after any scripts stop running?  Is this  dependent on the event?  I am specifically interested in mousemove and drag events.

Thanks

Comment: From what I can tell, the events are placed in a queue and then delegated to event handlers.

Comment: What do you mean "currently running"? Once a page is running, the event handler will be remembered till the page is closed, or the event removed.

Comment: You should read http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth and http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/. They focus on timers, but explain how the event loop works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean? Events that trigger javascripts?

If so then yes, the triggered script is remembered and put on the call stack.

Javascript is single threaded -- so an event that triggers a new script will have to wait until ***all*** other scripts on the stack are completed before it fires.

So if your drag or mousemove trigger a script then that trigger will be remembered.